# Run Script on logout/ shutdown ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, logout

I want to run some commands every time a user of an ubuntu 9.10 machine logs out or shuts down.  What is the best way to do this? Every user uses gnome if that helps.

Comment: this should really be under the "Linux & Unix" SE site... IMHO

Answer (score 3):

After some Googling I found [How to run a script on logout?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=147007) which says to add the script to $HOME/.bash_logout.

If that doesn't work, add

```
$HOME/.bash_logout
```

to /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default so it executes the logout script properly.

Seeing as before shutdown the user is logged off anyway, this should cover both bases.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12.04, `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` doesn't exist, where else I can place my script such that it executes on logout as well as shutdown?

Comment: /etc/gdm3/ is the slight correction needed

Answer (score 1):

If you are using KDE (I am using Ubuntu with kdm)

```
# From the kdm man page
#  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/kdm.1.html

/etc/kde4/kdm/Xreset - script to run as root after session exits

/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession - script to run as user after login of user

/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup - script to run as root before the login dialog appears

/etc/kde4/kdm/Xstartup -  script to run as root before session starts
```

**To test:**

Open the appropriate file i.e.

```
sudo emacs /etc/kde4/kdm/Xreset
```

Add a test command  (create a file in my home directory)

```
touch  /home/dericbytes/this-file-was-created-by-xreset
```

Then I logged out, and back in again, and checked if the new file was created

```
ls /home/dericbytes/this*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be bound to a specific display manager then you can put your scripts under `/etc/X11/Xreset.d/` which will be run as root every time you logout from an xsession.

For example: I want my virtualbox VM's to be on the savestate everytime a user logs out so I have a script that does that.

 `#!/bin/bash
su - $USER -c 'vboxmanage list runningvms | cut -d\" -f2 | xargs -I{} vboxmanage controlvm {} savestate'`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..well if you google "linux run script on shutdown", the first result is [a post on the Ubuntu forums with your answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185261):

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/foo.sh
```

This will allow you execute the script as a program.

To have a script run at shutdown, use this technique:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/foo.sh /etc/rc0.d/K10rensa.sh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/foo.sh /etc/rc6.d/K10rensa.sh
```

background on how this works: [An introduction to run-levels](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/212).

-

As a sidenote, should I refrain from indulging people with answers when it is clear that they haven't even tried searching the Internet first (I'm new here..)?

Comment: This does not handle logout events. Also, welcome to SO! The only time failing to search becomes an issue is when someone is asking a question that has clearly been asked (here) before. Googling prior is not required. As the link you provided clearly doesn't fully answer the question, its a good chance that the OP already saw it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [ConsoleKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html) dbus interface.