# how to record all who that login to my linux machines and records them

Tags: linux, security, history, auditd

I installed the package audit on my linux red-hat 6.x machine
in order to view the recored of each user that log to my linux machine

```
yum install audit
```

kit installation from: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-installing_the_audit_packages.html

after installation and restart the audit service as

```
service auditd start
```

I follow the audir.log file 
in order to see the users records

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

but from this log I see only the User IP's and when he login to my linux machine

the records of the linux command that user perfromed not apperars in the **audit.log**

can some one advice why we not see the history of linux command in **audit.log**?

example of **audit.log**

```
type=USER_START msg=audit(1422876162.936:152): user pid=28114 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35        addr=10.1.113.35 terminal=ssh res=s'
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1422876162.940:153): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0            ses=74236 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35            addr=10.1.113.35     terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1422876162.940:154): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35 addr=10.1.113.35 terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1422876162.940:155): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=99:c8:56:79:64:17:0b:67:b5:6c:e9:36:22:8a:b1:88 direction=? spid=28116 suid=0 '
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1422876162.940:156): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=6f:b9:bf:4f:84:1f:58:e5:d2:1c:94:1f:11:8e:26:61 direction=? spid=28116 suid=0 '
type=CRED_REFR msg=audit(1422876162.940:157): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35 addr=10.1.113.35 terminal=ssh res=success'
```

- remark in case this tool Audit can't do the records of each user , please help me to find other tool that can do the Job

Comment: [This link](http://superuser.com/questions/127454/run-script-on-logout-shutdown-ubuntu) shows you how to run a script on log-out. You could use this to record the command history file, though that may not be a complete solution. Ideally you would want a modified shell, but since users can invoke other shells you would need modifications to _all_ the shells on the system.

Comment: I googled **Linux shell auditing** and found [this useful summary](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/logging-every-shell-command/).