# RUN SCRIPT BEFORE SHUTDOWN in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, systemd

i have tried to run the script  before shutdown using systemd but its not working . I have created the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=test
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/test.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In script, I just remove the file.

Comment: Please show the specific method you have used to try to run this script on shutdown, and the evidence it is not doing so.

Comment: May be you can use this related answer: https://superuser.com/questions/127454/run-script-on-logout-shutdown-ubuntu?rq=1